# How to setup location in a simple class that is not an Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-location

I am using the `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get the user location from a simple class that is not an activity. How can I do that? I don't want to get the location from the activity class, just from a simple class. Is it possible? Example is below

```
class GetUserLocation {
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    suspend fun getLastLocation(): Map<String, Double> {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        val location = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.await()
        return mapOf(
            "lat" to location.latitude,
            "lng" to location.longitude
        )
    }
}
```

How can I get `this` in the following snippet if I am not in an activity class since the following snippet requires an activity, `this` only refers to the `GetUserLocation` class hence the error

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to pass context to any place where you want to get current location from device.

create an app module which provides a context

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(var app: App) {


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApp(): App = app

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context = app.applicationContext
}
```

and create a component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun context(): Context

}
```

and lastly you should create a component instance

```
val component by lazy {
        DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
                .build()
    }


class LocationUtils(app: Application) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var context: Context

     init {
        (app as? App)?.component?.inject(this)
      }
      fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

    }
```

Comment: The problem is the class is called from a repo class which has no connection to any activity class. The only option is to pass the context to three classes from the activity class like so "HomeActivity -> Viewmodel -> RepoClass -> GetUserLocation Class" which is inconvenient

Comment: ok then you should inject App instance or context to your repo class

Comment: this is not a problem you should only take care of activity lifecycle while getting location info from LocationServices

Comment: you need to start to listen location in onStart() lifecycle method and you should stop in onPause() and onStop() methods and you should again start to listen location in activity's onResume

Comment: in order to be able to handle this cycle you can implement https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle to obey activity's life cycle behavior

Comment: btw no need to pass a context through  "HomeActivity -> Viewmodel -> RepoClass -> GetUserLocation Class" just inject a context instance in your GetUserLocation class

Comment: Could you possibly change your answer and show a sample of how I could the inject in this case

Comment: do you use dagger in your app?

Comment: check out my answer again pls